# How to delete and reuse ZFS filesystems inside a Pool

Tags: filesystems, zfs

I have this ZFS Pool.

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    app         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t6d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c1t7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

It is divided this way:

```
app/oradata_smart_ora1   1.09G  11.9G  1.09G  /oradata/SMART/ora1
app/oradata_smart_ora2   7.07G  10.9G  7.07G  /oradata/SMART/ora2
app/oradata_smart_ora3   19.8G  16.2G  19.8G  /oradata/SMART/ora3
**app/oradata_smart_ora4    136G  30.1G   136G  /oradata/SMART/ora4
app/oradata_smart_ora5   11.8G  43.2G  11.8G  /oradata/SMART/ora5
app/oradata_smart_ora6   47.0G  28.0G  47.0G  /oradata/SMART/ora6
app/oradata_smart_ora7    122G  24.9G   122G  /oradata/SMART/ora7**
app/oradata_smart_redo1   601M  2.41G   601M  /oradata/SMART/redo1
app/oradata_smart_redo2   601M  2.41G   601M  /oradata/SMART/redo2
app/oradata_smart_redo3   601M  2.41G   601M  /oradata/SMART/redo3
```

I would like to erase the ora4,ora5,ora6 and ora7 and make just 1 big filesystem out of it all. This is an old server I was given (nothing is documented...) for reuse and Im trying to avoid to destroy the whole pool since the oracle installation resides in /app and only God knows Oracles license key.

How can I achieve this? Any other approach you want to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go:

```
# zfs destroy app/oradata_smart_ora4
# zfs destroy app/oradata_smart_ora5
# zfs destroy app/oradata_smart_ora6
# zfs destroy app/oradata_smart_ora7
# zfs create -o mountpoint=/whare/you/want/to/have/it -o quota=500m  app/new-big-fs
```

**NOTICE - all data on those file systems will disappear!**

And of course 'man zfs' is your friend.

Comment: How will it know how big the newbigzfs will be?

Comment: add -o quota=500m or size you need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!! Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. You could make a directory or ZFS filesystem under /app and move the data to the appropriate locations.

Comment: Mr. White!!! (IVE ALWAYS WANTED TO SAY THAT!) I'm totally unfamiliar with ZFS can you help me with the steps? Theres no data in the ora4-7 so I want to delete them and create a new big "ora4"